# Delete all "Profiles missing from Import"

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, user-profile-service, userprofiles

I have the below script which works perfectly fine to remove a user profile which is missing from import.

```
$caUrl="http://central-admin:12345";   
$site= new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($caUrl);  
$servercontext=[Microsoft.Office.Server.ServerContext]::GetContext($site);   
$userprofilemanager=new-object microsoft.office.server.userprofiles.userprofilemanager($servercontext);                
$p = $userprofilemanager.getUserProfile('Domain\user');   
foreach($user in $p)  
{  
    $userprofilemanager.RemoveProfile($user)  
}
```

In my case, I have around 1000 profiles with Domain\ which are missing from import. Can someone help me edit the above script so that i can remove all the domain\ users missing from import?

Timer job to delete the user profile is not enabled in our farm

Comment: Do you have a list of the users or is that part of the question i.e. how to identify those users?

Comment: @Bunzab I want to delete all the users whose domain starts with corporate\

Answer (score 1):

there are powershell command which will delete / purge all profile missing from import.

To view list of all obsolete users, run the below powershell ( give the identity of user profile)

```
$upa = Get-spserviceapplication <identity>
Set-SPProfileServiceApplication $upa -GetNonImportedObjects $true
```

To purge them run the below script.

```
Set-SPProfileServiceApplication $upa -PurgeNonImportedObjects $true
```

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff681014.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Thi should do what you need, but as ever do test first!

```
$userprofilemanager = new-object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($servercontext)
$profiles = $userprofilemanager.GetEnumerator()
$domainProfiles = $profiles | where {$_.AccountName.contains("corporate\")}
#DoubleCheck the contents of $domainProfiles before continuing...
foreach($profile in $domainProfiles) {
    $userprofilemanager.RemoveUserProfile($profile.AccountName)
    Write-host "Removed $($profile.AccountName)"
}
```